# Accessing ErrorMessage from within custom validation attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation, validationattribute

I want to be able to read the `ErrorMessage` string passed into a custom validation attribute so I can do some `string.Format()`ing on it. But I can't seem to find it?

So for example I have a custom attribute:

```
[IsDateBeforeFixedDate(4, 0, 0, ErrorMessage = "*The departure date should be between 4 days and 11 months")]
```

decalred as:

```
  public sealed class IsDateBeforeFixedDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
  {

    public IsDateBeforeFixedDateAttribute(int days, int months, int years) : base(days, months, years)
    {
      //I want to read the ErrorMessage string here! (i.e. "*The departure date should be between 4 days and 11 months")
    }
  }
```

`ErrorMessageString` doesn't contain it or `ErrorMessage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that if I access it in the `IsValid` method it contains the right string but it doesn't in the contructor